# Disable Jenkins Build button based on Parameters

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins jobs with parameters. I would like to disable the build button and enable only user enters valid value in string parameter. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 4):

There is one more extension to the above shown method - Above method checks for BUILD button on every Jenkins page as Simple Theme Plugin will be used.

In order to make the change at Job level - we can use Active Choices (https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/)

1. Go to configure section of the respective job
2. Select ***This project is parameterized*** option in General Tab
3. Add a new String Parameter named "Validating_Parameter"
4. Add another parameter of type Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter
5. In Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter - name can be empty and Choice Type should be of Formatted Hidden HTML
6. Add below groovy script by selecting **Groovy**:

```
return '''
<script>
function custom() {
    if (!document.querySelector("td.setting-main>div>input[value='Validating_Parameter']")) {
        return;
    } else {
        var inputElement = "";
        if (document.querySelector("td.setting-main>div>input[value='Validating_Parameter']").parentNode) {
            var childNodes = document.querySelector("td.setting-main>div>input[value='Validating_Parameter']").parentNode.childNodes;
            if (Object.keys(childNodes).length) {
                for (var key in childNodes) {
                    if ((Object.prototype.toString.call(childNodes[key]) == "[object HTMLInputElement]") && (childNodes[key].name == "value")) {
                        inputElement = childNodes[key];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /* init */

    if (inputElement) {

        var buildNumber = inputElement.value;

        setTimeout(function () {
            if (document.getElementsByName("parameters")[0].getElementsByTagName("button")[0]) {
                document.getElementsByName("parameters")[0].getElementsByTagName("button")[0].disabled = buildNumber.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s,\\!.-]{15,}$/) ? false : true;
            }
        }, 100);
    }

    /* Register keyup event */

    if (inputElement) {

        inputElement.onkeyup = function () {

            var buildNumber = inputElement.value;

            if (document.getElementsByName("parameters")[0].getElementsByTagName("button")[0]) {
                document.getElementsByName("parameters")[0].getElementsByTagName("button")[0].disabled = buildNumber.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s,\\!.-]{15,}$/) ? false : true;
            }
        }
    }

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', custom, false);
</script>
'''
```

Updated code so it doesnt fail on yui-gen3-button not found element. you can reference answer by @Mayur

Code referenced from above code by @Renjith

Comment: Hi @Simeen Khan, I have one more requirement here, which is if ```validating_Parameter``` does contain specific value, (say for eg. "Yes") I want to enable the Build button.. what should we need to do in that case

Comment: I am trying to test this solution, but I get error - build?delay=0sec:104 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null. What can be wrong with this?

Comment: @coder - Updated answer to disable jenkins button on any jenkins instance. Thanks to Mayur for helping in it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [validating string parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=58002722).

Or if you wanted to roll one yourself check out the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Form+Validation).

From the docs: "This is called "form validation", and Jenkins performs this on the server side." Meaning you wouldn't want to disable the build button if you use this method of validation.

Comment: Thanks, but by using "Validating Sting Parameter Plugin", build button is not disabled, it just fails the build. What i need is disable the button and enable only if it meets my criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Install Simple Theme plugin. This will help you to load your own JavaScript 
(https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Simple+Theme+Plugin )

Once its installed copy and paste following script to  "/var/lib/jenkins/userContent" as custom.js

Replace "X_BUILD_NUMBER" with your string parameter which you wanted to validate.

```
function custom() 

    if (!document.querySelector("td.setting-main>div>input[value='X_BUILD_NUMBER']")) {
        return;
    } else{
        var inputElement = "";
        if(document.querySelector("td.setting-main>div>input[value='X_BUILD_NUMBER']").parentNode){
            var childNodes = document.querySelector("td.setting-main>div>input[value='X_BUILD_NUMBER']").parentNode.childNodes;
            if(Object.keys(childNodes).length){
                for (var key in childNodes) {
                    if((Object.prototype.toString.call(childNodes[key]) == "[object HTMLInputElement]") && (childNodes[key].name == "value")){
                        inputElement = childNodes[key];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* init */

    if (inputElement) {

        var buildNumber = inputElement.value;

        setTimeout(function() {
            if (document.getElementById("yui-gen1-button")) {
                document.getElementById("yui-gen1-button").disabled = buildNumber ? false : true;
            }
        }, 100);
    }

    /* Register keyup event */

    if (inputElement) {

        inputElement.onkeyup = function() {

            var buildNumber = inputElement.value;

            if (document.getElementById("yui-gen1-button")) {
                document.getElementById("yui-gen1-button").disabled = buildNumber ? false : true;
            }
        }
    }

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', custom, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Simeen Khan. I was actively searching for this. I found your post helpful but there is one thing to change based on plugins used by jenkins.

For newer jenkins and newer "Build With Parameters" plugin the documentElementID will be changed to gen4 or higher.

We can find these details using inspecting build button on build with parameter page of jenkins.

for example on my jenkins it is `<button type="button" tabindex="0" id="yui-gen4-button">Build</button>`.

for this Simeen's script will be like below:

```
return '''
<script>
function custom() {
    if (!document.querySelector("td.setting-main>div>input[value='Validating_Parameter']")) {
        return;
    } else {
        var inputElement = "";
        if (document.querySelector("td.setting-main>div>input[value='Validating_Parameter']").parentNode) {
            var childNodes = document.querySelector("td.setting-main>div>input[value='Validating_Parameter']").parentNode.childNodes;
            if (Object.keys(childNodes).length) {
                for (var key in childNodes) {
                    if ((Object.prototype.toString.call(childNodes[key]) == "[object HTMLInputElement]") && (childNodes[key].name == "value")) {
                        inputElement = childNodes[key];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

 


    /* init */

 

    if (inputElement) {

 

        var buildNumber = inputElement.value;

 

        setTimeout(function () {
            if (document.getElementById("yui-gen4-button")) {
                document.getElementById("yui-gen4-button").disabled = buildNumber.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s,\\!.-]{15,}$/) ? false : true;
            }
        }, 100);
    }

 

    /* Register keyup event */

 

    if (inputElement) {

 

        inputElement.onkeyup = function () {

 

            var buildNumber = inputElement.value;

 

            if (document.getElementById("yui-gen4-button")) {
                document.getElementById("yui-gen4-button").disabled = buildNumber.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s,\\!.-]{15,}$/) ? false : true;
            }
        }
    }

 

}

 

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', custom, false);
</script>
'''
```

Comment: Does this still work? I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null` because I believe my script can't access the outer scope lets say. It can't find the button

Comment: Hi @Garbem. Yes it will work just need to change selector for build button. I have found new code which works in any jenkins jobs irrespective of yui version.

```document.getElementsByName("parameters")[0].getElementsByTagName("button")[0].disabled=true```

Comment: I managed to make it work also after I installed this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Simple+Theme+Plugin